# Simple UI - how to?

Tags: android, android-layout

Using Android studio 3.1, and I have a strange problem, I can't edit my UI,
I enter the content_main.xml, using the design tab, blueprint, anything i drag to the blueprint is not appearing, I use the infer constraints, still not helping
this is my XML code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="Name"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="53dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="168dp" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would't recommand using the UI designer, you don't get the feeling of what you are really doing with it. You should learn how to directly edit the XML file, this isn't really harder and at least you know what you are doing.

Comment: I'm coming from WPF programming(damn i like VS so much), but i can't get this to work

Answer (score -1):

You must drag the widget to the component tree
[ver imagen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qz4rx.png)

Comment: maybe try to empty the android studio cache in the file> invalidate caches / restart